# On Click Event With Symbol Icon

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, symbols

I am trying to make a `SymbolIcon` clickable using `XAML`. I have been doing some research on the best way to accomplish this and I have not found a solution. The end product is I would like to fire an event in my code behind when the symbol is clicked. Here is my symbol:

```
 <SymbolIcon x:Name="mySymbol"
      RelativePanel.Below="myOtherProperty"
      RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
      RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
      Symbol="Contact"
      Foreground="Black"/>
```

Can anyone advice on how I can make this symbol clickable?

Comment: I suppose putting it inside a button won't fly?

Comment: Doesn't [SymbolIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbolicon#events) support Tapped/DoubleTapped events by default?

Comment: I will try the Tapped event and let you know

Comment: @ChrisW. If you can place that as a proposed solution I will be happy to make it as resolved. Worked like a charm, I was not aware of that attribute.

Comment: Haha I think Matt beat me to it, no worries as long as you found a remedy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SymbolIcon` inherits from `UIElement` and so has `Tapped` and `DoubleTapped` events.

Just handle one of these. e.g.

```
<SymbolIcon
    DoubleTapped="UIElement_OnDoubleTapped"
    Symbol="Contact"/>
```